# ExtJS 4: TreeStore with both static and dynamically-loaded data?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I'm making a TreePanel that looks like this:

[image]

At the moment I have it "mocked up" with the following code:

```
treePanel.setRootNode({
    text: 'Root',
    expanded: true,
    children: [
        {
            text: 'General Settings',
            icon: kpc.cfg.baseUrl.img+'/icon_gears-bluegreen.gif',
            leaf: true
        },
        {
            text: 'Users',
            icon: kpc.cfg.baseUrl.img+'/icon_users-16x16.gif',
            expanded: true,
            children: [
                {
                    text: 'Dummy User 1',
                    icon: kpc.cfg.baseUrl.img+'/icon_user-suit.gif',
                    leaf: true
                },
                {
                    text: 'Dummy User 2',
                    icon: kpc.cfg.baseUrl.img+'/icon_user-suit.gif',
                    leaf: true
                },
                {
                    text: 'Dummy User 3',
                    icon: kpc.cfg.baseUrl.img+'/icon_user-suit.gif',
                    leaf: true
                },
                {
                    text: 'Dummy User 4',
                    icon: kpc.cfg.baseUrl.img+'/icon_user-suit.gif',
                    leaf: true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
});
```

**How can I load the individual users dynamically (i.e., via a store)?** In other words, how do I make a TreeStore that is a mixture of both static and dynamically-loaded items?

Thanks!

Comment: What part remains static?  The general settings? Will the tree somehow work without the dynamically loaded data? If the answer is no, then I would maybe suggest just loading everything (provided the tree really is this simple and the overhead is low).

Comment: @LittleTreeX: The 'Settings' node is static. I'd like all of the 'user' nodes to be loaded dynamically from the server (i.e., from a RESTful API).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The solution that worked best for me was to:

1. create two tree stores--one with the static content, another set up to load my User models from the server.
2. "graph" the dynamically-loaded tree onto the static tree.

I wrote up a little tutorial that includes a runnable demo [here](http://www.clintharris.net/2011/how-to-use-extjs-4-treepanels-with-both-static-data-and-model-stores/) (in case anyone wants a more detailed answer), but at a high level the code looks like this:

```
Ext.define('demo.UserModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['id', 'name', 'profile_image_url']
});


var userTreeStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {

    model: 'demo.UserModel',

    proxy: {
        type: 'jsonp',
        url : 'https://myserver/getusers',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'users'
        }
    },

    listeners: {

        // Each demo.UserModel instance will be automatically 
        // decorated with methods/properties of Ext.data.NodeInterface 
        // (i.e., a "node"). Whenever a UserModel node is appended
        // to the tree, this TreeStore will fire an "append" event.
        append: function( thisNode, newChildNode, index, eOpts ) {

            // If the node that's being appended isn't a root node, then we can 
            // assume it's one of our UserModel instances that's been "dressed 
            // up" as a node
            if( !newChildNode.isRoot() ) {
                newChildNode.set('leaf', true);

                newChildNode.set('text', newChildNode.get('name'));
                newChildNode.set('icon', newChildNode.get('profile_image_url'));
            }
        }
    }
});

userTreeStore.setRootNode({
    text: 'Users',
    leaf: false,
    expanded: false // If this were true, the store would load itself 
                    // immediately; we do NOT want that to happen
});

var settingsTreeStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
    root: {
        expanded: true,
        children: [
            {
                text: 'Settings',
                leaf: false,
                expanded: true,
                children: [
                    {
                        text: 'System Settings',
                        leaf: true
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'Appearance',
                        leaf: true
                    } 
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
});

// Graft our userTreeStore into the settingsTreeStore. Note that the call
// to .expand() is what triggers the userTreeStore to load its data.
settingsTreeStore.getRootNode().appendChild(userTreeStore.getRootNode()).expand();

Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
    title: 'Admin Control Panel',
    store: settingsTreeStore,
});
```

Comment: +1 ... this was very informative, and was able to read some of the content.  Athough, it seems like something in this page becomes unresponsive and crashes Google Chrome on the link provided above.  http://www.clintharris.net/2011/how-to-use-extjs-4-treepanels-with-both-static-data-and-model-stores/

Answer (score 2):

I believe the `node` parameter will help you. Set `autoLoad: false`, then leverage the `beforerender` event of the actual tree panel. Inside the event call the store's load function, and pass it a `node`. The docs state that if this is ommited from the `load()` call, it will default to the root node. It would appear that you could leave your settings in the root node and then by calling load and passing it a child node, you'd be able to update just the users.

Please see: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.TreeStore-method-load for reference. Note that this load function is not the same as in `Ext.data.Store` (`Ext.data.TreeStore` does not inherit from `Ext.data.Store`).

I have not had the opportunity to test this, but it seems promising.

Answer (score 2):

I have a very similar problem, and while I haven't gotten it to work completely like I want it to, it mostly works.  I have `autoLoad: false` and added this event handler:

```
beforerender: function(comp, opts) {
    var node = this.getRootNode();
    node.appendChild({test: 'Recent', id: 'recent', expandable: true, expanded: false});
    node.appendChild({text: 'Current', id: 'current', expandable: true, expanded: false});
    node.appendChild({text: 'All', id: 'all', expandable: true, expanded: false});
}
```

The 3 immediate children of the root are static, then the proxy makes a request to populate them when I expand them (passing the appropriate id).

I also had to suppress the root node from loading with a listener on the **store**:

```
        listeners: {
            beforeload: function(store, operation, opts) {
                if (operation.node.data.id == 'root') {
                    return false;
                }
            }               
        },
```

Hope this helps.  It seems like there should be a better way!?!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my function to convert normal data to treeStore data, you can use that. By that way, you don't need treeStore anymore:

Records: array of record.
Text: name of item (get from record)
Children: name of children (default is 'children')

```
dynamicReportsStore.load({
    scope: this,
    callback: function (records, operation) {
        if (operation.isComplete()) {
            var tree = this.buildTreeByRecords(records, 'name');
            treePanel.getRootNode().removeAll();
            treePanel.getRootNode().appendChild(tree);
        }
    }
});



buildTreeByRecords: function (records, text, children) {
var childs = [],
    results = [],
    tree = [];
records = Ext.Array.map(records, function (record) {
    return {
        text: record.get(text) || record.get('id'),
        leaf: record.get('leaf'),
        expanded: true,
        parentId: record.get('parentId'),
        id: record.get('id')
    };
}, this);
Ext.each(records, function (record) {
    if (Ext.isEmpty(childs[record.parentId])) {
        childs[record.parentId] = [];
    }
    childs[record.parentId].push(record);
}, this);
Ext.each(records, function (record) {
    if (!Ext.isEmpty(childs[record.id])) {
        record[children || 'children'] = childs[record.id];
        results.push(record);
    }
}, this);
Ext.each(results, function (result) {
    if (result.parentId === 0) {
        tree.push(result);
    }
}, this);
return tree;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a reader to achieve this effect in what I feel to be an elegant fashion.  Mind you this is with a flat store and may look a little different with a tree store.  The concept should translate.

```
Ext.define('Ext.data.reader.a8PolicyReader', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.reader.Json',
    read: function(response) {
        var staticStuff,
            responseArr;

        // Static stuff
        staticStuff = [{name: 'some static user', id:1}, {name: 'another user', id:2}];
        // extract response
        responseArr = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
        // shove them together
        responseArr.concat(staticStuff);
        // read
        this.readRecords(responseArr);
    }
})
```